# C Passing file pointer into a function

Tags: c, file, function, pointers

I have a problem with passing file pointers. How do I pass it if there is a function with a file pointer within a function(void writequest in my code)? It was working before I put in the void writequest. The program itself is supposed to read from one file that is filled with movie names and then put them into another. Of course, feel free to note any other failures in my code.

```
void writequest(int no)
{
    int i, j, loop_ctrl, destination;
    int movement;
    char lib[loop_ctrl+1][92];
    int write_nr[loop_ctrl], sorting[destination];
    char searching[92];
    char *c;
    FILE *watched;
    FILE *temp;
    FILE *refrom;
    FILE *reto;
    FILE *towatch;
    if(no==1)
    {
        printf("No match found.\n");
    }
    else if(no==0)
    {
        printf("Do you wish you write them into a file?\n1 - Yes\n0 - No\n");
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if(j==1)
        {
            tofile(watched, temp, refrom, reto, destination, loop_ctrl, write_nr, lib, movement);
            close(towatch, watched, temp, refrom, reto);
            remove("To_watch.txt");
            rename("temp.txt", "To_watch.txt");
        }
        else if(j==0)
        {
            printf("Alright then\n");
            close(towatch, watched, temp, refrom, reto);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a `FILE` pointer to `writerequest`? Why not just add an extra argument to the function for that?

Comment: Also, if you pick a name like Dumbarse it's hard for people to take your questions very seriously.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is like "here's a bunch of code, don't know why it does not work, help me". If it's what @JoachimPileborg said, it's even worse as you have already examples in the code you posted. Edit: Just wanted to add some adivce: Reduce the question to the main problem, if you want to show code, reduce the code the way it shows only (really only) the problem you have.

Comment: Note taken, haven't posted here before. Essentially, yeah, that is my question, why does it not work? I've tried writing it like this: 
    void writequest(int no, FILE *watched, FILE *temp, FILE *refrom, FILE *reto, FILE *towatch)
However, that had no effect. Also: I found the name to be rather fitting to my current question

Answer (score 0):

```
  char *c;
    FILE *watched;
    FILE *temp;
    FILE *refrom;
    FILE *reto;
    FILE *towatch;
```

These are all pointers. So if you call upon them in your functions your asking for the value inside them. That's their address. except for movement. What is a bit strange.

It is vital to know what the functions exactly are before anyone can say what the problem is.